# wordpress get post_id where meta_value =

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to query the wordpress post_meta table by meta_value.

I would like to output all post_id's where the meta_value is = to _parent_product. Here is my code:

```
$posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT *, FROM $table WHERE meta_key='_parent_product' ");
foreach ( $posts as $post ){

$id = $post->post_id;

echo $id;

}
```

The above outputs nothing and im not quite sure why? Can anyone see anything wrong?

Comment: Can't explain the down vote either, up voted ;).

Comment: There is a `,` (comma) behind `SELECT *`, is it a typo?

Comment: Thanks again dbf! I didnt even notice that. Put it as an answer and il accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057036/wordpress-get-post-id-where-meta-value?noredirect=1#comment26420957_18057036),

There is a comma (`,`) behind `SELECT *,`. Therefor the given SQL is invalid and will fail to retrieve any results.